# Convert Dynamic Rows to Fixed Column

Tags: excel

I need to convert dynamic number of rows to fixed number of columns. how to do it? Here is what I want to do:

```
A1      B1      C1
A2      B2      C3
-       B3
```

convert to

```
A1      A2
B1      B2      B3
C1      -       C3
```

Blank spaces are indicated by dashes(-).

Comment: have you tried to `copy >> paste with transformation`?

Comment: Since you are transposing a dynamic number of rows to a fixed number of columns, how do you determine the number of columns. Is there some kind of cutoff? Your current example is just a simple transpose, which you can do with Paste Special>Transpose. It's the dynamic part that's not clear.

Comment: I have maximum 3 columns. transformation doesn't work sine there blanks in certain colmns. Sorry in my original example. C3 should be in row2

Comment: How do you determine that C3 should end up in the third column in the result table, rather than in the second column? I see that there a 3 in both B3 and C3, but presumably that commonality would be lost if you were talking about arbitrary values in the locations in the original data set. Guess I don't get the question.

Answer (score 1):

Transposing with blanks works fine in Excel 2010, if you are having a problem transposing in an earlier version, add a column to the left of column A (new column A), fill it with any value, copy and paste special; transpose. then delete the added values.  Remember you can not paste transpose into the space you are taking from, so paste into E1, then delete the source columns after paste.